# Intuitive way to understand tree recursion - Write code to check if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

**Question:**

> Implement a function to check if a binary tree is balanced (i.e. no
>   two nodes differ in height from the root by more than 1).

**Solution:**

```
int maxDepth(Node *root)
{
   if(!root) return 0;

   return 1 + max(maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right));
}
int minDepth(Node *root)
{
   if(!root) return 0;

   return 1 + min(minDepth(root->left), minDepth(root->right));
}
bool isBalanced(Node *root)
{
   return maxDepth(root)-minDepth(root) <= 1;
}
```

Can someone help me understand the intuition behind this solution? I'm struggling to "see" the recursion behind tree algorithms. I know that `maxDepth` and `minDepth` are supposed to find the height of the node of maximum depth and minimum depth in the tree, respectively, but I don't understand how the recursion works to do that.

More importantly, I don't quite know how I could come up with this solution on my own. So any tips as to how to approach tree problems in general would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you starting to learn with recursion with tree algorithms?

Comment: Ouch. You should try easing your way into thinking recursively. Try some problems from http://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1.. They will help you understand it better.

Comment: you try to understand two concepts at once: one not that simple: trees and one complicated: recursion. You should tackle them separately

Comment: But do remember, every recursive solution has an iterative counterpart and vice versa.

Comment: @austinwernli Not really. You can do recursion with a utility stack instead of system stack but it's still recursion. Recursion that only does tail calls can however since they are iterative loops. Handling of trees are always recursive.

Comment: Recursion is a difficult topic for a beginner.I suggest you to learn it separately from trees for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand is look at the example:

```
   a
  / \
 b   c
    / \
   d   e
```

when you call `maxDepth` on root node 'a' what will the following code do?

```
return 1 + max(maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right));
```

it will return `1` + **max** of `maxDepth('b')` or `maxDepth('c')`

`maxDepth('b')` will return `1` because:

```
1 + max( maxDepth(NULL), maxDepth(NULL) ) = 1 + (max (0,0)) = 1 + 0 = 0;
```

the above gets `NULL`s from *'b'->left* and *'b'->right*

so, getting back to maxDepth('a') now we know that it returns:

```
maxDepth('a') = 1 + max( 1, maxDepth('c'));
```

`maxDepth('c')` will follow the same steps and return 2. Hence:

```
maxDepth('a') = 1 + max( 1, 2 ) = 1 + 2 = 3
```

for *minDepth()* the flow is the same with the only difference in using **min**() instead of **max**().